# How to filter out duplicate rows from child model before being displayed in Django ListView

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am using two related models in my Django application. The objects so created in the models are being displayed using the listview class. In the child model I can create multiple rows based on some key date. When I try to display values from both the models (linked with an FK field), all the child objects for the respective FK fields are displayed (wherever more than one records are there).

Is there a way that I may use `select distinct` to filter out duplicate rows. I have tried:

```
myModel.objects.distinct().order_by('id')
```

but still getting all the child rows for the parent `id`.

In my template I am using:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {{ obj.<field1> }}     <!-- field1: Parent model field -->
    {% for item in obj.<child_model>_set.all %}
        {{ item.<field2> }}     <!-- field2: Child model field -->
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

### My question is:

**How do I filter out duplicate rows before the data is displayed?**

**The backend is sqlite3 on Django 2.0.6 / Python 3.6**

### Edit

**This is how the current list is being generated:**

[image]

The first column is **pk** of parent model record and the next column is for child records' **pk**.

**What I am trying to get is:**

**Option 1:** Get only the last (date wise) record for the combination of **parent/child rec numbers** (i.e. for parent record number **32**, only the combination **32|156** should be displayed, and those with values for child records **149** and **148** should not be displayed).

**OR**

**Option 2:** Get all combination of records grouped by ParentModel pk field and ChildModel pk field to be shown separately in successive rows (as you can see, the **multiple values for a parent record** (wherever existing), is being shown in the **same row, successive columns**).

PS. I am sorry things are getting quite dense here.

### Edit 2

This is the class view I am using for displaying data:

```
class myRateListView(ListView):
    template_name = "rate_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'ratelists'
    model = ParentModel

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(myRateListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'rate_item_list': ChildModel.objects.order_by('field3'),

        })
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
       return ParentModel.objects.values('field1', 'childmodel__field2').distinct()
```

Here I am getting error :

> Cannot resolve keyword 'childmodel' into field. Choices are....

I think my class view is wrong??

### Edit 3

Models and view details:

### models.py

```
class TptRateDoc(models.Model):
    tpt_rate_doc_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True.....)
    loc_from = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='locn_from', on_delete=.......)
    loc_to = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='locn_to', on_delete=.......)
    create_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now,...)

class TptRateItems(models.Model):
    tpt_doc_header = models.ForeignKey(TptRateDoc, on_delete=...)
    tpt_rate_item_num = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=10,...)
    tpt_rate_valid_from_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='From date')
    tpt_rate_valid_to_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='To date')
    tpt_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True,...)
```

### views.py

```
class TptRateListView(ListView):
    template_name = "tpt_rate_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'tptrates'
    model = TptRateDoc

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TptRateListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'tpt_rate_item_list': TptRateItems.objects.order_by('tpt_rate_valid_to_date'),  # .distinct()
        })
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
#        return TptRateDoc.objects.order_by('loc_from')
        return TptRateDoc.objects.values('tpt_rate_doc_number', 'tptrateitems__tpt_rate_item_num').distinct()
```

**Note:** The commented out parts are what I had tried earlier.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to catch the returned queryset of distinct filter to a new queryset? I mean like this:(* according docs, distinct will come after order_by())

```
queryset = myModel.objects.order_by('id').distinct()
```

and then pass this updated queryset to template.

```
return render(request, "html_file.html", { "objects": queryset})
```

On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply. This translates to a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query. Here’s the difference. For a normal distinct() call, the database compares each field in each row when determining which rows are distinct. For a distinct() call with specified field names, the database will only compare the specified field names.

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated when you consider objects to be "distinct". If you do somthing like

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.distinct()
```

your queryset will contain all the `MyModel` instances. Why? Because each instance will have a different `id` (or pk) even if all other fields are identical. So for `distinct()` to work you need to specifify the fields to consider, i.e. you need to use `values()`. So in order to get a queryset containing the distinct values of field2 in your ChildModel you would need to do something like

```
queryset = ChildModel.objects.values('field2').distinct()
```

So if I understand you correctly you want to display all "field1" values and associated "field2" values where "field2" values should be unique. What I would recomend is a 2 step approach.

First in your view create a queryset containing distinct combinations of field1 and field2, e.g.:

```
queryset = ParentModel.objects.values('field1', 'childmodel__field2').distinct()
```

and then pass this queryset to your template

```
return render(request, 'parent_child.html', {'objects': queryset})
```

Then, in order to do the hierachical rendering, you can use the {% regroup %} template tag as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup):

```
{% regroup objects by field1 as obj_list %}

<ul>
    {% for obj in obj_list %}
    <li>
        {{ obj.grouper }}
        <ul>
            {% for child in obj.list %}
            <li>
                {{ child.childmodel__field2 }}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

As OP has not posted his models these are the models used for this answer

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ChildModel(models.Model):

    parentmodel = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field3 = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: On using `ParentModel.objects.values('field1', 'childmodel__field2').distinct()` error is being raised `Cannot resolve keyword 'childmodel' into field. Choices are...` **(the choices being all fields of model ParentModel and none from the ChildModel)**. I am updating my question with additional info.

Comment: You really should post your models if you want hints on what went wrong in your code. Added two example models on which my anser is based - tested with Django 3 and working

Comment: I tested your view with the example models I posted, it works. Also tested with Django 2 - it works. So I strongly suspect it has something to do with your models. As I said: Please post the models you are using.

Comment: Added both the models as well as the view (with model's field references). You may like to check it pls. **PS.** If you think I might remove the old codes if it helps readability.

Comment: I tested your models and your views: They work as expected, no exceptions raised. Are you sure have all your migrations applied?

Comment: After reading your comment tried to run migrations again but getting notice "No changes detected".

Comment: **As before, getting this error:** `Cannot resolve keyword 'tptrateitems' into field. Choices are: loc_from, loc_from_id, loc_to, loc_to_id, create_date, id, tpt_rate_doc_number`

Comment: If you are certain that your child model really has got a fk relationship to the parent I am running out of ideas. I really cannot reproduce your error even using the same Django and python versions you are using. Sorry

Comment: If you pls check the image I had added in my first **edit**, the number **33** is from the parent model (`TptRateDoc`) and **associated** values like number **151**, dates and prices are from the child model (`TptRateItems`). One other thing: **What is the meaning of the error message that I keep getting about `Cannot resolve keyword...`**?**